# Logout and return to welcome view. ionicHistory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to create a controller that clear the cache of navigation in the app for make a Logout button.

My idea is cleaning the Session ID when I tap the Logout Button so I can go the Welcome View with the app "closed".

Im trying to use **$ionicHistory** for this:

```
.controller('LogoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicHistory', function($scope,$state,$ionicHistory) {
  $scope.logout = function(){
      $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
        //now you can clear history or goto another state if you need
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
        $state.go('welcome');
      })
    };
}])
```

But when I tap the button, It does nothing.

```
<button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="logout()" >Logout</button>
```

Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use it without `clearCache` and `clearHistory`. Does it than navigate? Did you debug the controller and get `logout` called correctly?